# question on java list remove

Tags: java, list, data-structures, arraylist

The method [`public boolean remove(Object o)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28Object%29) of [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) removes an object from list but does not shift the elements following.Just nulls the object value.
IMHO this is an uninintuitive design choice since the size of the list before and after removal remains the same.
Is there an elegant way to get a list with the elements shifted?

Thanks

Comment: _"but does not shift the elements following.Just nulls the object value"_, where did you get that info from?

Comment: @Bart:I have seen it during debugging.The list was an arraylist.After remove there was the same number of elements but one was just null

Comment: @user384706: As you said below you're talking about the internals of an ArrayList.  This is an efficiency trade off that the implementation of ArrayList makes, instead of reallocating a new array or iterating over the array and shifting elements, it just changes the value of "first element" pointer and the array size value.  The way it works externally is unchanged (other JVM implementations may actually do this differently).  Why do you care about the internals here?  You can always call `.toArray()` to get a correctly-sized array.

Comment: @Tony:I do not care about the internals.I used it, I removed an element and then during a for loop because I was not checking for null pointer the code crashed.I did not think at this point that, to a valid list, after removing an object, if I loop I should also check for null value

Comment: @Tony:Call `toArray()`?This is good idea.May be post it as answer

Comment: Actually looping through a collection that is Iterable is quite "bad" programming style. You should either iterate using an iterator object or use the alternative for syntax like this `for(Object x: varWithCollection){ dosomething.. with the var x}`

Comment: @ITroubs:I was looping using an iterator and stubbled on this

Comment: @user384706 i doubt that you used an `Iterator` Object

Comment: I edited my anser with an example on how to use an Iterator.

Comment: @user: show us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem you're facing and we might be able to explain what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not what it does. The element is removed and all indices following it are reduced by one. What makes you think it acts differently?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Java API [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) it sais that the remove function of List DOES shift

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.

EDIT:

Main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList<A> x = new ArrayList<A>();
        A one = new A("one");
        A two = new A("two");
        A three = new A("three");
        A four = new A("four");
        A five = new A("five");
        A six = new A("six");
        A seven = new A("seven");
        A eight = new A("eight");
        A nine = new A("nine");
        A ten = new A("ten");

        x.add(one);
        x.add(two);
        x.add(three);
        x.add(four);
        x.add(five);
        x.add(six);
        x.add(seven);
        x.add(eight);
        x.add(nine);
        x.add(ten);

        for(A item:x){
            System.out.println(item.getStr());
        }

        x.remove(four);

        Iterator<A> i = x.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            A item = i.next();
            System.out.println(item.getStr());
        }
    }
}
```

The A Class:

```
public class A {
    private String str;

    public A(String x){
        this.str = x;
    }

    public String getStr(){
        return this.str;
    }

}
```

works perfectly! no null pointer exception.
This is how it should be done. the first For loop is the alternative syntax for what i did wit the Iterator object. Actually Java automatically translates the first for loop in something that looks like the while loop.

Comment: You are wrong.This mentioned only in the api `E remove(int index);`.I am talking about `remove(Object o)`

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object) read it. it doesn't even mention indexing. the implementation should remove the first occurence if it exists and thus reduce the size. you shure could end with the same size after calling remove(Object o) BUT only if o is NOT contained in the list so no matter if it is contained or not after you call that function you will have one item of o less.

Comment: I saw the link.The part in your post is from the doc of the API `remove(int index)` http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int). I am not sure what you mean "if o is NOT contained in the list".If it is not then nothing is removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [ArrayList remove implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28java.lang.Object%29), it uses a local method fastRemove(index) as follows:-

/*
 * Private remove method that skips bounds checking and does not
 * return the value removed.
 */

```
private void fastRemove(int index) {
    modCount++;
    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work
}
```

It does use arraycopy which is a proof that you get whole new list of fresh objects and not the null filled in between. Is this a proof?

Answer (score 1):

The contract for `java.util.List` implies that calling `remove` will cause the `size()` to be decremented.  If you're talking specifically about `java.util.ArrayList` then you might be right about the internal array not shifting its elements, but this is an implementation detail that shouldn't matter to you in 99% of all cases.  If it still does matter, then you're trying to optimize for a specific situation and you should probably implement your own `List` or use something like `java.util.LinkedList`.

Comment: Nope, the `ArrayList` **definitely** shifts all higher elements to the "left" (that's why deletes near the start of the list are relatively expensive).

Comment: and that's why doing list.remove(0) list.size() times will empty the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

Either your observation is wrong or you are using some other kind of List implementation (and not ArrayList) that doesn't shift the elements to the right of the element being removed. Can you post your code?

If you look at the java.util.ArrayList source code in JDK8, you will see that the remove(Object o) method effectively copies the elements to the right of the element being removed, to the same array starting from the index of the element being removed. Look at the ArrayList [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.remove%28java.lang.Object%29)  for more info:

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is an array of the data, then just call `toArray()`.