# How to leftshift an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm using an ArrayList to hold a history of objects. Each new object I add using the .add method, like:

```
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
{
    if(currentWord != null)
    {
        wordHist.add(currentWord);
    }

    if(wordHist.size() > WORDHIST_MAX_COUNT)
    {
        wordHist.remove(0);
    }
}
```

However I don't want this to grow indefinitely, but to be limited to a certain value. If it reaches this maximum value, I want the oldest object (index 0) to be removed, and the rest to be left shifted, so previous index 1 is now index 0, etc.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Implement or find on internet CircularArrayList

Comment: Somewhat similar, not exact duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543384/question-on-java-list-remove

Comment: If `ArrayList.remove(0)` is not working as you expect, could you please show us a complete example?

Comment: @Rob that's not a complete example.  I'd prefer something that compiles and runs (feel free to strip down the code, eg. use an ArrayList of String or something), so I can test it for myself, otherwise it's very hard to help.

Comment: @sverre, a good link to include in such comments: [sscce.org](http://www.sscce.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArrayList is not really a good choice **in this case**, but it can by done by calling **remove(0)** method. But if you want to do that efficiently, a linked list is better

(edited to make it clear that LinkedList is not generally better than ArrayList, but only in this case)

Comment: It is not a good idea to generalize.  While ArrayList is not the best choice if you are only doing this particular operation, it may be the best choice overall ... considering *the total mix* of operations that the application needs to do.

Comment: from this perspective, ArrayList and Linked list are not different. You can implement your own list, and keep track (in int) what position represents begin but i think even that is not necessary since the concept of beginning gets lost when overriding

Comment: The reason I want to do this is to limit the amount of memory used (its for an Android app). So using an int to track the beginning would not help me accomplish this.

Comment: I think what Op De Cirkel suggests is that you implement a cyclic list, which indeed would save you memory.

Comment: Stephen, Since Rob mentioned it is used for memory management, linked list should be better in most of the operations as it almost always access something in sequence. So adding, removing state, or navigate to a previous/next history state will always results in a O(1) time and little memory operation.

Comment: @Rob, i was commenting on user658991's answer. My point was, that Cyclic List can be implemented in both variants (Array, Linked) with the same performance O(1) adding

Comment: @user658991, But, for instance swapping two elements becomes O(n) instead of O(1).

Comment: another thing to consider is that if the elements are small (ints), then linked lists need almost twice more memory

Comment: @aioobe, yes, but when will you need to swap 2 elements when you are dealing of a list of history as the question asked?

Comment: @Op De Cirkel, you are totally right, the best solution should be a circular list, unless the author insist in using the code he posted in the question, linked list would be the choice.

Comment: Swapping is not needed for this particular application. Only adding to the end, and removing the first.

Comment: It was just an example to emphasize Stephen C's first comment on this answer.

Comment: I guess what i didn't make clear is LinkedList is a better choice in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

> ***If it reaches this maximum value, I want the oldest object (index 0) to be removed***

Then do `wordHist.remove(0)`. That will remove the element at index 0.

To be precise:

```
wordHist.add(new Word("hello"));
if (wordHist.size() > MAX_SIZE)
    wordHist.remove(0);
```

As user658991 states however, you should be aware of that this is a linear operation, i.e., takes time proportional to the number of elements in the list.

You could do this in constant time using `LinkedList` methods `add` and `removeFirst`.

Another option would be to wrap an array, or ArrayList in a class called something like `CircularArrayList`. In circular list structures you'll override the oldest element when adding a new one.

### Edit:

Your code works fine:

```
import java.util.*;
class Test {
    
    static int WORDHIST_MAX_COUNT = 3;
    static List<String> wordHist = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public static void add(String currentWord) {

        // VERBATIM COPY OF YOUR CODE

        if (true/*event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP*/)
        {
            if(currentWord != null)
            {
                wordHist.add(currentWord);
            }

            if(wordHist.size() > WORDHIST_MAX_COUNT)
            {
                wordHist.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        add("a");
        add("b");
        add("c");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < wordHist.size(); i++)
            System.out.printf("i: %d, word: %s%n", i, wordHist.get(i));
        System.out.println();
        
        add("d");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < wordHist.size(); i++)
            System.out.printf("i: %d, word: %s%n", i, wordHist.get(i));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
i: 0, word: a
i: 1, word: b
i: 2, word: c

i: 0, word: b        <-- b is now at index 0.
i: 1, word: c
i: 2, word: d
```

Comment: Actually I tried this, but this just makes element at index 0 equal to null. The next "add" performed adds another Word object to position MAX_SIZE

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong. [Here](http://ideone.com/XRSwI) is a demo illustrating `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `remove( )` method.

Using `remove(0)` will remove the element from the 0th index.

Comment: Actually I tried this, but this just makes element at index 0 equal to null. The next "add" performed adds another Word object to position N+1, where N=max index.

Answer (score 0):

U can use list.remove(index)// here index being '0', this internally shifts rest of the array up. An alternative solution wud be to use a queue or dequeue.

Comment: Actually I tried this, but this just makes element at index 0 equal to null. The next "add" performed adds another Word object to position N+1, where N=max index.

Answer (score 0):

One simple implementation of what Op De Cirkel suggested

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SimpleCircularHistory {

    private int sizeLimit, start = 0, end = 0;
    boolean empty = false;
    private List<String> history;

    public SimpleCircularHistory(int sizeLimit) {
        this.sizeLimit = sizeLimit;
        history = new ArrayList<String>(sizeLimit);
    }

    public void add(String state){ 
        empty = false;
        end = (end + 1) % sizeLimit;
        if(history.size() < sizeLimit){
            history.add(state);
        }else {
            history.set(end, state);
            start = (end + 1) % sizeLimit;
        }
    }

    public String rollBack(){
        if(empty){ // Empty
            return null;
        }else {
            String state = history.get(end);
            if(start == end){
                empty = true;
            }else {
                end = (end + sizeLimit - 1) % sizeLimit;
            }
            return state;
        }
    }

    public void print(){
        if(empty){
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }else {
            for(int i = start;; i = (i + 1) % sizeLimit){
                System.out.println(history.get(i));
                if(i == end) break;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleCircularHistory h = new SimpleCircularHistory(3);
        h.add("a");
        h.add("b");
        h.add("c");
        h.add("d");
        h.add("e");
        h.add("f");
        h.print();

        h.add("X");
        h.add("Y");
        h.rollBack();
        h.rollBack();
        h.print();
        h.add("t");
        h.add("v");
        h.add("w");
        h.print();
        h.rollBack();
        h.rollBack();
        h.rollBack();
        h.print();
        h.rollBack();
        h.print();
    }

}
```

This would print out :

```
d
e
f

f

t
v
w

Empty
Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've noticed this behaviour in adroid's lists too. It's REALLY irritating.

Anyway, there is a way to get around it if I don't mind object creation/destruction and the resulting garbage collection (NEVER do this in a onDraw of a surfaceview or something).

What I do is basically have two tracking int's; one to place the new object, and one to remove it:

```
                int trackInt = 0;
                int removeInt = 0;

                //and then, in the method/class you use this:

                Object newobject = new Object();
                //add to list
                objectList.add(trackInt, newobject);
                trackInt++;
                if (bugList.size() > 20) //20 is the max number of object you want, ie the maximum size of the list
                {
                    objectList.remove(removeInt);
                    trackInt = removeInt;
                    removeInt++;
                    if (removeInt > 19) //remember, the list is zero indexed!
                    {
                        removeInt = 0;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Commons-collections has exactly what you're looking for:

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html